# Ubuntu 16.04 shows blank screen forever

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, hardware

After the grub menu, I am a blank screen instead of the login screen. If I switch to the command line, I get the following error lines:

```
[  0.037567] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 3: Machine Check: 0 Bank 0: d400024000040150
[  0.037640] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 1ffffa62427d5
[  0.037708] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:506E3 TIME 1230804254 SOCKET 0 APIC 6 microcode d6
```

I can't comprehend the error properly but it looks like it's a motherboard issue. I also made sure it's not an OS issue, as it perfectly runs on another machine.

Can you please explain the specific issue, and how to solve this (or is it solvable at all)?

Comment: Honestly, that looks like a failed DIMM in the first slot of the board, but it appears that there might be another line about ECC.  Try swapping RAM around in the system and see if the error changes.  If it does, you found the bad DIMM.  If not, then it might be a bad slot on the motherboard

Comment: @Terrance Well, I just changed the slot, and now I am getting only first line. So, as per your explanation, both the motherboard slot and DIMM itself looks damaged.